# SUM Data in 1 line SQL

Tags: sql

lets say that i have table like this

```
ITEMNAME   JANUARY    FEBRUARY
Table      20         100
Chair      30         50
```

and i want to show it like this

```
ITEMNAME   JANUARY    FEBRUARY    SUM
Table      20         100         120
Chair      30         50          80
```

the question is how to show that table with query?

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design. Normalise your schema.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT item, january, february, (january+february) AS sum
FROM table
```

It hasn't been tested yet, but I think it works